# Multiple search in mongodb with morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I've two classes: User and Project.
The project class have ONE user (the owner of project).

In search method, it returns a list of user after a method, and with this list of users,
i need to find all projects that contains the user of one item of the list os users that i have.

For solve this, i put a for and i call the find (morphia basicDao find method) for each user in for iteration, and the result i added in a array, and manually i remove the duplicated projects.

Someone knows a better method to solve my problemn? Maybe a morphia method that do this for me...

Sorry for bad english. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `$in` operator, which is [documented online](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24in). As you might expect, [Morphia's equivalent](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/Query#Operators) is called `in`, too.

Here's an example of using `in`:

```
List<String> userList;
List<Project> projects = Project.find().field("user").in(userList).asList();
```